# Advice on offline crash reporting

Tags: c++, c, .net, wpf, crash

I'm looking for an advice regarding crash reporting for cross-language solutions. Having a number of applications written in C/C++, dealing with user-space and kernel-space, and .Net/C#, for calculations and visualization, or a combination of both. Those applications frequently running on systems without any internet or intranet connections, I was wondering if there are any crash reporting systems allowing you to do manual or intermediate crash reporting. Where the user possibly needs to copy/upload over a report containing the (mini)dumps and or logs (whatever is necessary to debug the application).

I've checked a few solutions like Sentry and Microsofts AppCenter but they both seem to required an internet connection in some way or another. Or, am I going to have to develop my own solutions for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use logging to capture the data. Using (say) nlog you could write stack trace to a file. You can specify filters and only write errors. Then they grab that file off disk onto a usb and attach to an email... From some other machine.

Comment: Hi @Andy, that's pretty much what I'm doing right now, at least for the .Net stack. I also build a wrapper around nlog to allow me to specify/change logging levels runtime while normally you could only specify that from a config file on startup. If this is my only option then I'm going to have to build a platform which will allow me to do what I want to do.